# Does Microsoft Project 2010 have any sample files? 

Tags: microsoft-office, microsoft-project

I can't find any sample files like .mpp or whatever for Microsoft Project. Can someone please help me locate some?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to:

[Microsoft® Project 2010 Step by Step Practice Files](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780735626959-files/)

[office.microsoft.com - Microsoft Project 2010 Templates](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/results.aspx?qu=template&av=zpj140&queryid=ae78a7e3-9d7c-4bea-949e-b11f27a5010f)